# Add Permanent Include and Library Path for CUDA C/C++ Compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, linker, cuda, include-path, nvcc

I'm currently doing some work that includes the use of **CULA** library and GPU Computing SDK's library.

When compiling I have to use the following flags when compiling with NVCC:

```
-lcutil_x86_64 -lcula_core -lcula_lapack -lcublas -lcudart -lcuda -I$CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR/common/inc/ -L$CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR/lib/ -L$CULA_LIB_PATH_64
```

Even though that works just fine, I'm tired of having to specify the include and library paths every time. Is there some way I can run the compiler without having to provide the following arguments:

```
-I$CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR/common/inc/ -L$CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR/lib/ -L$CULA_LIB_PATH_64
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a Makefile....

Comment: @talonmies That would work too, but I don't want to go through the trouble of making a makefile for every little program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA ships with documentation for nvcc. The file is nvcc.pdf. In particular read up on the Nvcc.profile file.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. However, seeing as how the libraries could change, I think I should follow talonmies advice, and just do Makefiles.

Comment: I agree. When I start a new project, I tend to copy some old project that I have and use it as a starting point. If you do the same, it's not much of a problem to include the Makefile from the old project.

Comment: I don't find the `nvcc.pdf` under `/usr/local/cuda/doc/pdf`